# Journals of math history?

Tags: soft-question, math-history

In a related question to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153883/who-is-a-math-historian), in what journals do math historians publish their article in? Brian M. Scott provided a link to [Judy Grabiner](http://bernard.pitzer.edu/~jgrabine/)'s, who is a math historian, home page and it seems that she publishes in general mathematical journals for the most part, such as the American Mathematical Monthly. However there is mention of a journal that seems to be exclusively for math history called "[Historia Mathematica](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/historia-mathematica/)". Are there any other journals exclusively for math history?

Comment: Math Monthly is very nice, but it is not a research journal. I have never seen a history of math paper in a mathematics research journal.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yup I believe you are right about that.

Comment: There is also [Archive for History of Exact Sciences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_for_History_of_Exact_Sciences). This journal does not deal exclusively with mathematics, but you can find some interesting math-related papers there.

Comment: André Nicolas: **Russian Mathematical Surveys** publishes, or at least used to (I don't have access to any volumes after 1999), quite a number of very good historical articles. In particular, I have photocopies of several lengthy articles on Russian research in descriptive set theory that discuss things I know of no other references for in English (e.g. Lyapunov's work on $R$-sets, Keldysh's work on Luzin's problems, etc.).

Comment: There is also the British Society for the History of Mathematics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BSHM Bulletin. Journal of the British Society for the History of Mathematics. 
[Taylor & Francis](http://www.tandfonline.com/loi/tbsh20), 4 Park Square, Milton Park, Abingdon 0X14 4RN England. 
ISSN: 1749-8430. 
E-ISSN: 1749-8341. 
3 issues/vol./yr.

[Revista Brasileira de História da Matemática](http://www.rbhm.org.br/). An International Journal on the History of Mathematics, 
Sociedade Brasileira de História da Matemática Caixa postal 1631 CEP 59.078-970 Campus Universitario Natal RN Brazil. 
ISSN: 1519-955X.

[Gaṇita Bhāratī](http://www.mdppl.com/journals/ganita-bharati.html). Bulletin of the Indian Society for the History of Mathematics. 
Formerly Gaṇita-Bhāratī. 
MD Publ. Pvt., Ltd. "MD House'' 11 Darya Ganj, New Delhi 110 002 India. 
ISSN: 0970-0307. 
2 issues/vol./yr.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for this!

Comment: Add Archives for History of Exact Sciences, it has math stuff too.

Comment: Yes, one could add a lot of other journals that have math history, but OP's question was, "Are there any other journals exclusively for math history?" and I chose to interpret literally. By the way, I don't claim the list I've given is exhaustive.

Comment: The last link is dead.

Comment: @Gigili, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Do you know by any chance how can I access the volume 24 of Ganita Bharati in the United States?

Comment: @Deepak, no, but I bet a librarian would know.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, just to let you know, your link to Ganita Bharati is dead, but a new one has been provided in an answer by greg (who as a new user could not just post a comment.)

Answer (score 2):

Web link for Ganita Bharati:
http://www.mdppl.in/journal/ganita-bharati-bulletin-indian-society-history-mathematics

Also consider Revue d'histoire des mathematiques:
http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/RevueHistoireMath/

Answer (score 0):

Closely related:
International Journal for History of Mathematics Education
http://www.comap.com/historyjournal/

Comment: Why didn't you just add this to your other answer?

Comment: @MagicMan, the poster is a new, unregistered user.  I have a vague recollection that unregistered users *cannot* edit their posts.

Comment: @BarryCipra Interesting. I guess that's somewhere over on meta. I thought about answering with *Mathematics Magazine*, but this question is very old.

Comment: @MagicMan, greg's first posting updates the link to Ganita Bharati, which is now a dead link in Gerry Myerson's answer.  New users can't post comments, only answers.

Comment: @BarryCipra Do you have a link for that information per chance? On meta or in the help center somewhere?

Comment: @MagicMan, sorry, no.  As I said, it's a vague recollection, and I could be wrong.